# Is there any Ctrl - R kind of command search in vim?

Tags: vim

we have `Ctrl - R` command to quickly search bash command history. Is there any similar command to use in vim command history & also search history.

Comment: Modified the question to add "search history" for more clarity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't have enough rep to comment, but in regards to your question about search history:

You can use `q/` just like `q:` to view the search history.

Alternatively you can press `CTRL-F` from command or search mode to bring up the history.

Answer (score 3):

No. But you can use `q:` to open the command history window, where you can edit and execute previous commands, and search for them, just like in a regular buffer (use `/` and friends to search there).

`Ctrl-R` in Vim is reserved for something else entirely (accessing registers from insert or command mode, redo in normal mode).

Comment: q: only shows the commands, will it not show search history? I mean all the searches done using `/` command

Comment: You asked about "command history". "search history" is, as Caek says, `q/`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin I have made that does exactly what Ctrl-R does on the shell, to use it you start command mode and type Ctrl-R and just start typing your search. If there's anything typed before invoking it though it assumes default command mode Ctrl-R functionality.

https://github.com/goldfeld/ctrlr.vim

Answer (score 0):

To recall a previous command or search, start command or search mode (`:` or `/`, respectively) and start typing the beginning of whatever past line you're looking for. When you think you've supplied enough to search for, hit <kbd>Up</kbd> to go back through previous commands or searches that started with that string.

Comment: Unlike Up/Down
`CTRL-P` discards whatever you've typed and scrolls back through all previous searches/commands.
`CTRL-N` moves forward.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for that correction. (I obviously use up/down most of the time.)